# SOLR uniqueKey with solr.UUIDField

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, unique-key

Trying to use solr.UUIDField to generate a uniqueKey field.

```
<fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />


<field name="uid" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NEW" />

<uniqueKey>uid</uniqueKey>
```

But for some reason its not working.

Error message:

> {msg=SolrCore 'db' is not available due to init failure: uniqueKey field (null) can not be configured with a default value (NEW). Schema file is .\example-DIH\solr\db\schema.xml,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'db' is not available due to init failure: uniqueKey field (null) can not be configured with a default value (NEW). Schema file is .\example-DIH\solr\db\schema.xml
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:818)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:289)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: uniqueKey field (null) can not be configured with a default value (NEW). Schema file is .\example-DIH\solr\db\schema.xml
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:608)
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.(IndexSchema.java:166)
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.create(IndexSchemaFactory.java:55)
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:69)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:554)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:592)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:271)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:263)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       ... 1 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: uniqueKey field (null) can not be configured with a default value (NEW)
>       at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:536)

**UPDATE:**

After i made the Changes that leoh suggested in the answer bellow i recieved following error message:

I also forgot to mention that its when using dataimporthandler i recieve the error messages.

```
{msg=SolrCore 'db' is not available due to init failure: Error initializing QueryElevationComponent.,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'db' is not available due to init failure: Error initializing QueryElevationComponent.
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:818)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:289)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error initializing QueryElevationComponent.
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:834)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:625)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:557)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:592)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:271)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:263)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error initializing QueryElevationComponent.
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent.inform(QueryElevationComponent.java:242)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:631)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:829)
... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid UUID String: '1'
at org.apache.solr.schema.UUIDField.toInternal(UUIDField.java:89)
at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.readableToIndexed(FieldType.java:391)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent$ElevationObj.<init>(QueryElevationComponent.java:138)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent.loadElevationMap(QueryElevationComponent.java:311)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent.inform(QueryElevationComponent.java:225)
```

I tried to remove following but then nothing is indexed:

```
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent" >
    <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
    <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
</searchComponent>
```

Comment: that might only work on solr 3. Which version of solr are you using?

Comment: solr-4.6.0, what should i use on this version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David2342

To configure the uuid field in solr 4.6, you may need the following configurations

```
<!--schema.xml-->

<fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />

<field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

<!--solrconfig.xml-->
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid">
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="fieldName">id</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>


 <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
       <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="update.chain">uuid</str>
       </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Here is a link to a sample configuration that works for me : https://gist.github.com/leoh/8967328

Answer (score 1):

For your second error "init failure:" you need to modify uid in elevate.xml file. The default path to elevate file is

```
@ SOLR_HOME\example\example-DIH\solr\solr\conf
```

probably your path to that file may be different.

If you want to know where exactly in elevate.xml file then Please attach your elevate.xml file.