# Why my configuration for SOLR uniqueKey with solr.UUIDField generates ERROR SolrException missing required field: id

Tags: solr, uuid, unique-key

I want to use [UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory](https://UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory) to automatically generate **UUID** as the **uniqueKey** field for all new documents that will be created. I followed the given instructions & also tried already given solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736564/solr-uniquekey-with-solr-uuidfield) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143842/solr-uuid-with-error-document-is-missing-mandatory-uniquekey-field-id) but nothing worked. I am using **solr version 9.1.1** on **Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS**.
I amgetting the error:  **missing required field: id**.
Following is my current configuration which is generating error:

```
solr-spec: 9.1.1
lucene-spec: 9.3.0

managed-schema.xml
-----------------------
<fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true"/>
<field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="_root_" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" />
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>


solrconfig.xml
---------------
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid">
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="fieldName">id</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>

 <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
       <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="update.chain">uuid</str>
       </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

**Error Message:**

```
RequestHandlerBase   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: [doc=null] missing required field: id
```

Please advise what I am missing?

Comment: How are you invoking the `uuid` update processor chain?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have only configured as mentioned above. I am new to solr & assumed other all background work is automatically done by solr. New documents creation request is sent using PHP SolrClient. Kindly share any relevant link for the guidance.

Comment: No update processor chains are applied unless asked for, you can explicitly tell Solr to run the `uuid` chain by appending `?update.chain=uuid` to the URL when the request is performed, or you can add it to the configuration to always have it be applied by Solr, either through `initParams` (schemaless) or `requestHandler`: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/update-request-processors.html#configuring-a-custom-chain-as-a-default

Comment: @MatsLindh ```requestHandler``` is already in use as mentioned above in my question but its not working:  ```<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
       <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="update.chain">uuid</str>
       </lst>
</requestHandler>```

Comment: @MatsLindh Do we need to send empty ```id``` field or it will be automatically added by solr? Surprisingly if I send request without any ```id``` field I get error but if I send following request with empty ```id```, solr successfully creates new document with uuid: ```$product = new SolrInputDocument();
$product->addField('id', '');
$product->addField('category', 'shirt');``` Is it the right way to use uuid for id field?

Comment: I've never used the processor, so I can't say. I'd, just as you, expect the field to be added if missing so that it was always present.